# organizing MANY hexagons

Tags: javascript, grid, konvajs, hexagonal-tiles

im creating a boardgame, with a hexagon shaped tilebased map. i used konva to create the hexagons/polygons. the way i went about it was to just create a variable for each polygon, but this ended up as a 1000+ lines of code (as the map has about 50 hexagontiles) so im wondering if there is a more efficient way since its hard to keep track of so many lines of code.

this is how 1 polygon looks. (im intending to place a sprite, where the player will be able to move the sprite such as in chess, moving from one tile to another by clicking the mouse etc.)

```
var polyA = new Konva.RegularPolygon({
  x: 600,
  y: 400,
  sides: 6,
  radius: 400,
  rotation: 90,
  stroke: "black",
  strokeWidth: 5
});
```

and here is the code for loading the tiles. as you can see its very long.

```
board.add(polyA, polyB, polyC, polyD, polyE, polyF, polyG, polyCr, polyDr, polyEr, polyFr, polyGr, polyA1, polyB1, polyC1, polyD1, polyE1, polyF1, polyCr1, polyDr1, polyEr1, polyFr1, polyGr1, polyB2, polyC2, polyD2, polyE2, polyF2, polyG2, polyCr2, polyDr2, polyEr2, polyB3, polyC3, polyD3, polyE3, polyCr3, polyDr3, polyEr3, polyFr3, polyB4, polyC4, polyD4, polyE4, polyCr4, polyDr4, polyEr4, polyB5, polyC5, polyD5, polyCr5, polyDr5, polyEr5, polyB1u, polyC1u, polyD1u, polyE1u, polyF1u, polyCr1u, polyDr1u, polyEr1u, polyFr1u, polyGr1u, polyB2u, polyC2u, polyD2u, polyE2u, polyF2u, polyG2u, polyCr2u, polyDr2u, polyEr2u, polyB3u, polyC3u, polyD3u, polyE3u, polyCr3u, polyDr3u, polyEr3u, polyFr3u, polyB4u, polyC4u, polyD4u, polyE4u, polyCr4u, polyDr4u, polyEr4u, polyB5u, polyC5u, polyD5u, polyCr5u, polyDr5u, polyEr5u);

stage.add(board);
```

Comment: I think this will do better in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. More of a refactoring issue than an actual bug/unexpected behaviour etc

Comment: thanks, i have to wait 40 minutes to post again :( but ill post it there.

Comment: I'll upvote this so you'll get more rep. Good luck and happy coding. Maybe you'll get a response here who knows ^^